# Proper Splashscreen just black

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

So, i've been seen a lot of tutorials showing "the proper way" of implementing a SplashScreen for android, using the following code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

^ **drawable/splash_background.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- Splash Screen theme. -->

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
</style>
```

^ **values/styles.xml**

```
  package com.rws.jsonclassifier;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Handler;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

^ **SplashActivity.java**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rws.jsonclassifier">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

^ **AndroidManifest.xml**

I'm using the code and following the seteps as they're shown in the tutorials, but for some reason instead of a blue background with the app icon I get a full-black-screen.
Any ideas?

Comment: Its not the `SplashScreen` is blank its `MainActivity` cause you have started it inside onCreate . Use a Handler with Delay and you will see the splash . And also mentions the  lot of tutorials you have seen for this. I don't think any splash tutorial will start an Activity directly in `oncreate()`.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154 There's the code i've used xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens because you are not using a `Handler` to navigate to the next `Activity`. I implemented this in one of my apps as well.

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
     android:name=".view.LaunchActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:launchMode="singleTask"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launch">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
      </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Launch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/activity_launch</item>
</style>
```

**activity_launch.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/product_logo_windesheim" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then make `LaunchActivity` extend  just `Activity`.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
     super.onCreate(bundle);
     new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, ScheduleActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
         }
     });
 }
```

See full source here:

https://github.com/gi097/MyWindesheim/

Comment: Thanx for your time and the reference! I'll check it out to compare it to my code, bot implementing the handler just makes the black screen longer... :(

Comment: Did you try to replace `AppCompatActivity` with just `Activity`?

Comment: Yep, but it's still black hahaha

Comment: I see that you accepted my answer. What did you finally do to make it work?

Comment: I pretty much implemented your code into my project and it worked, using the github link as reference to see how was the ScheduleActivity.class implemented

Answer (score 0):

After

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

add

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
```

also add handler just as @Nabil said

Comment: There's no activity splash on the layout folder... I thought that was the idea begind this kind of implementation (?)

Answer (score -1):

Use a handler inside onCreate and try adding a new splash.xml layout view for splash activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
       }
       }, 2000);
    }
```

you can add your own design in splash.xml layout

If you still want to use your way of coding, then i think the error is in **drawable/splash_background.xml**

Add ic_launcher to your drawable folder and then change

```
<bitmap
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

to

```
<bitmap
android:gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
```

Comment: Thanx for your time!
Using this code I still get the black screen. A longer one, but still just black S:

Comment: add a new splash.xml layout also and design it as you want

Comment: i have edited answer, if you still haven't got a solution then try now